# How to optimize EF performance on foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

Here is my code; as you can see, I am saving changes for each row, but I want to make performance faster because I have large amount of data every time, like 50.000 or 100.000 rows or more. This takes a lot of time to finish.

How can I improve my EF `SaveChanges` performance? I tried bulksave, bulkupdate with some third party library, but it is not updating in the database. This takes 2 hours to update 50.000 rows. I want to improve time for this method.

```
private void TransferOrders()
{
    using (var context = new BbsfDbContext())
    {
        context.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant);
        context.DisableFilter("LanguageSpecificFilter");

        var sapOrders = context.SapOrders
                               .Where(p => p.VBTYP != null && 
                                           p.VBTYP.ToLower() == OrderDocumentType && 
                                           p.IsRead == false)
                                //.Where(p => p.VBTYP != null && p.VBTYP.ToLower() == OrderDocumentType && p.Id == 3025)
                               .Where(p => !ActiveUsersOnly || context.Users.Where(u => u.IsActive).Select(a => a.MainVendor.SapCode).Contains(p.KUNNR))
                               .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
                               .ToList();

        if (sapOrders.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in sapOrders)
            {
                try
                {
                    var order = context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VBELN);

                    var isExist = context.SapOrderDetails.Any(p => p.DOCNUM == item.DOCNUM);

                    if (isExist)
                    {
                        var salesOrganization = context.SalesOrganizations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VKORG);

                        if (salesOrganization == null)
                            continue;

                        var distributionChannel = context.DistributionChannels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VTWEG);

                        if (distributionChannel == null)
                            continue;

                        var salesDepartment = context.SalesDepartments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.SPART);

                        if (salesDepartment == null)
                            continue;

                        var salesOffice = context.SalesOffices
                                                 .FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VKBUR &&
                                                     p.SalesOrganization.Id == salesOrganization.Id &&
                                                     p.DistributionChannel.Id == distributionChannel.Id &&
                                                     p.SalesDepartment.Id == salesDepartment.Id);
                        if (salesOffice == null)
                            continue;

                        var ordererCustomer = context.Customers
                                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.KUNNR &&
                                                     p.SalesOrganization.Id == salesOrganization.Id &&
                                                     p.DistributionChannel.Id == distributionChannel.Id &&
                                                     p.SalesDepartment.Id == salesDepartment.Id &&
                                                     p.SalesOffice.Id == salesOffice.Id);

                        var recipientCustomer = context.Customers
                                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.KUNWE &&
                                                     p.SalesOrganization.Id == salesOrganization.Id &&
                                                     p.DistributionChannel.Id == distributionChannel.Id &&
                                                     p.SalesDepartment.Id == salesDepartment.Id &&
                                                     p.SalesOffice.Id == salesOffice.Id);

                        if (recipientCustomer == null)
                            recipientCustomer = context.Customers
                                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.KUNWE &&
                                                         p.SalesOrganization.Id == salesOrganization.Id &&
                                                         p.DistributionChannel.Id == distributionChannel.Id &&
                                                         p.SalesDepartment.Id == salesDepartment.Id &&
                                                         p.SalesOffice == null);

                        if (ordererCustomer == null || recipientCustomer == null)
                            continue;

                        if (order == null)
                        {
                            order = new Order
                                {
                                    SapCode = item.VBELN,
                                    SapOrderDate = item.AUDAT,
                                    DocumentType = context.DocumentTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VBTYP),
                                    SalesDocument = context.SalesDocuments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.AUART),
                                    BaseAmount = item.NETWR,
                                    TotalTax = item.MWSBT,
                                    Currency = context.CurrencyDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.WAERK),
                                    SalesOrganization = salesOrganization,
                                    DistributionChannel = distributionChannel,
                                    SalesDepartment = salesDepartment,
                                    SalesGroup = context.SalesGroups.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VKGRP && p.SalesOffice.Id == salesOffice.Id),
                                    SalesOffice = salesOffice,
                                    RequestedDeliveryDate = item.VDATU,
                                    SASNo = item.BSTNK,
                                    SASOrderDate = item.BSTDK ?? item.AUDAT,
                                    OrdererCustomer = ordererCustomer,
                                    RecipientCustomer = recipientCustomer,
                                    //PRSDT
                                    Status = OrderStatus.Approved,
                                    Type = OrderType.MainVendor,
                                    DeliveryAddress = context.CustomerAddressBooks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainVendor.Id == ordererCustomer.Id && p.SubVendor.Id == recipientCustomer.Id),
                                    CreationTime = DateTime.Now,
                                    LastModificationTime = DateTime.Now,
                                    CreatorUserId = context.Users.First(p => p.UserName == AbpUserBase.AdminUserName).Id,
                                    LastModifierUserId = context.Users.First(p => p.UserName == AbpUserBase.AdminUserName).Id,
                                    IsSubVendorOrder = false,
                                    IsSameDayDelivery = false,
                                    RepresentativeId = context.Users.First(p => p.UserName == AbpUserBase.AdminUserName).Id
                                    //ProductionSite
                                    //RejectionReason =//todo:bu silinmeli iptal kalem bazında burada statu olmalı
                                };
                                var savedOrder = context.Orders.Add(order);
                                context.SaveChanges();

                                order.SASNo = BbsfConsts.KeasOrderNumberPrefix + savedOrder.Id;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                order.SapOrderDate = item.AUDAT;
                                order.DocumentType = context.DocumentTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VBTYP);
                                order.SalesDocument = context.SalesDocuments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.AUART);
                                order.BaseAmount = item.NETWR;
                                order.TotalTax = item.MWSBT;
                                order.Currency = context.CurrencyDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.WAERK);
                                order.SalesOrganization = salesOrganization;
                                order.DistributionChannel = distributionChannel;
                                order.SalesDepartment = salesDepartment;
                                order.SalesGroup = context.SalesGroups.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SapCode == item.VKGRP && p.SalesOffice.Id == salesOffice.Id);
                                order.SalesOffice = salesOffice;
                                order.RequestedDeliveryDate = item.VDATU;
                                order.SASNo = BbsfConsts.KeasOrderNumberPrefix + order.Id;
                                //order.SASOrderDate = item.BSTDK.HasValue ? item.BSTDK : item.AUDAT;
                                order.OrdererCustomer = ordererCustomer;
                                order.RecipientCustomer = recipientCustomer;
                                //PRSDT
                                //order.Status = OrderStatus.Approved;
                                order.DeliveryAddress = context.CustomerAddressBooks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainVendor.Id == ordererCustomer.Id && p.SubVendor.Id == recipientCustomer.Id);
                                order.LastModifierUserId = context.Users.First(p => p.UserName == AbpUserBase.AdminUserName).Id;
                                order.LastModificationTime = DateTime.Now;
                                //ProductionSite
                                //RejectionReason =//todo:bu silinmeli iptal kalem bazında burada statu olmalı
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (order != null)
                            {
                                var orderDetails = context.OrderDetails.Where(p => p.OrderId == order.Id).ToList();
                                orderDetails?.ForEach(p => context.OrderDetails.Remove(p));
                                context.SaveChanges();

                                context.Orders.Remove(order);
                                context.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }

                        item.IsRead = true;
                        item.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Error(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Error During IDOCOperations " + ex.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a lot of memory you could preload many of the dbsets as lists in memory.
Also if you are not changing the data of something you are getting from a dbcontext the AsNoTracking() gives quite a nice performance bump for large datasets as it doesn't have to set up tracking of changes in the returned objects.

Comment: avoid call SavesChanges() in foreach, rather outside

Comment: Remove `if (sapOrders.Any())` - it achieves nothing. `if (ordererCustomer == null || recipientCustomer == null)
                            continue;` The `orderCustomer` check can be moved earlier.

Comment: `SaveChanges` will store all changes at once. That's the whole point - don't access the database until you have to, and you *don't* have to

Comment: In general though, the answer to any loop/cursor related question about SQL is *don't!*. SQL is a set based language, it doesn't use loops. It retrieves *all* relevantrows in a single operation, where a loop requires at *least* N operations. Using loops even has a name `RBAR`:Row-By-Agonizing-Row. When you do that on the *client* the result is far worse as each query requires another network roundtrip

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using joins in your initial query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping

Comment: Even joins won't be needed if the entities have proper relations defined between them. There should be an `Order.SapOrder` or `SapOrder.Orders` property that links the two together so you *don't* have to use any of those `FirstOrDefault` calls

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems that the different actions could be grouped and then executed in a single step.

For example:

- Create a list of all items that must be updated with `item.IsRead = true; item.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;`, and execute everything together at the end in one step
- In the same way, create a list with all the orders to remove, and then execute in a single step at the end

I don't know if this will be applicable according to the context and/or the application, it's just an idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your configuration for Lazy Load feature, both global and by-property levels.

When you are executing ToList() in sapOrders, you're executing your query (and loading result in memory) and you might be executing side queries when you get Orders, SalesOrganizations, and so on...

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) article to improve your loop.

On the other hand, you could use async queries and parallel programming in your loop, so, for each non-dependant task in it, you can create an async Task method and run all of them concurrently.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async) and [here](https://medium.com/@hoagsie/youre-all-doing-entity-framework-wrong-ea0c40e20502) you are some articles I hope help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid calling `.SaveChanges()` in your loop, but rather do it at the very end, you'll be much better off, as you avoid multiple round trips to the DB. That being said, if you're looping over 50,000 items doing this you'd probably want to batch that to some degree, maybe every 1,000 you call it.

Unfortunately, you've got the complication of needing the result of an order creation on save to store on another column though. Perhaps if you keep track of the orders you are creating, when you do the batch save, straight after you could do it you do a batch set of `SASNo` for each just created and another `.BulkSaveChanges()`?

For your later save changes (where you remove the order details, save, remove order, save), I can't see the need to do that in multiple steps, but maybe my EF is rusty and it'll complain. Ideally, I would remove all those calls to `.SaveChanges()` and do that in the bulk op every 1000.

Above would significantly cut the number of DB network calls, assuming `BulkSaveChanges` can handle all this. Basically I'd be aiming for below, but at the end of the day, this could potentially be done better/faster without EF.

```
using (var context = new BbsfDbContext())
{
    var sapOrders = ...;
    var ordersCreated = new List<..>(); // might wanna initialized this with a size if you have a rough gauge on what % will need creation of loop

    //if (sapOrders.Any()) // not needed
    //{
        foreach (var item in sapOrders.Select((x, index) => new { x, index }))
        {
            try
            {
                var order = ...;
                var isExist = ...;

                if (isExist)
                {
                    // ...

                    if (order == null)
                    {
                        order = new Order { ... };
                            var savedOrder = context.Orders.Add(order);
                            //context.SaveChanges();

                            //order.SASNo = BbsfConsts.KeasOrderNumberPrefix + savedOrder.Id;
                            ordersCreated.Add(order);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Do updates
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if (order != null) // shouldn't need this
                        //{
                            var orderDetails = context.OrderDetails.Where(p => p.OrderId == order.Id).ToList();
                            orderDetails?.ForEach(p => context.OrderDetails.Remove(p));
                            //context.SaveChanges();

                            context.Orders.Remove(order);
                            //context.SaveChanges();
                        //}
                    }

                    // ...

                    if (index % 1000 == 0)
                    {
                        context.BulkSaveChanges(); // bulk save of 1000 loops of changes

                        foreach (var orderCreated in ordersCreated)
                        {
                            orderCreated.SASNo = BbsfConsts.KeasOrderNumberPrefix + savedOrder.Id;
                        }
                        context.BulkSaveChanges(); // bulk save of x num of SASNo sets
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.AsNoTracking()` could also help, but I'm not too sure how you'd manage that if you wanna do a single query for the data upfront but only track some of the parts that query returns. Potentially it's possible with a bit of googling.